# getUser() in "onAuthenticationSuccess" with Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

In FOSUserBundle configuration, I have "success_handler" (with Symfony
2.7). "onAuthenticationSuccess" is true. But, I want to getUser() in
"onAuthenticationSuccess". I tried to insert @ security.token_storage
in the service, but the token is still empty . Do you know how? :)

Answer (score 0):

You should include it in the constructor as well:

```
public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $token_storage)
{
    $this->token_storage = $token_storage;
}
```

And then use something like:

```
$iduser = $this->token_storage->getToken()->getUser()->getIduser();
```